# How do I get a barplot when I use actionbutton to input a gene from a dataframe column?

Tags: r, shiny

Here is my sample data:

```
        mean_data <- data.frame(
              Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
              matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
            )
            names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
```

**The  column is Gene sets.**

I mean when I input one gene and the click the actionbutton, the barplot will appear but I tried  several times it doesn't work.

My code here:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)
    
    mean_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    sd_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    
    ###
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("123"),
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(
            "selectGeneSymbol", 
            "123:", 
            choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
            multiple =F,
            width = 400,
            selected = 1 
          ),
    
          actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
        ),
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("all")    
        )
      )
      
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      plot_data1 <- reactive({
        subset(mean_data, colnames(mean_data)[-1] %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
      })
      
      global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL)
      
      observeEvent(input$plot1, {
        global$out <- plotOutput("plot1", height=500)
      })
      
    
      
      output$all <- renderUI({
        global$out
      })
      
      p1 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot1,
                               input$all), {
                                 ggplot(data = mean_data, aes(x = mean_data$Name, y = mean_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol],fill=Name)) +
                                   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                                   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = mean_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
                                   theme_classic2() +
                                   rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
                                   theme(legend.position = "none") +
                                   labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
                               })
    
      
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ p1() })
      output$plot3 <- renderPlot({ grid.arrange(p1(),p2(), ncol=1) })
      
      
    }
    
    # Create Shiny app ----
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**I combined mean_data and sd_data before and it works well.**

Now I use both of them and **choose the column of mean_data** as the input but the actionbutton doesn't work .The barplot always appear before clicking the button.

I tried several times but I don't know where the code I have to change.

Comment: I need help please

Comment: Your desired effect  is that the plot should be updated after I click the button `FPKM`, right?

Comment: Firstly you need to check the react of your selectInput. Be patient.

Comment: I guess the problem is here `observeEvent(input$plot1, {
        global$out <- plotOutput("plot1", height=500)
      })`. The react of select should only to update the input data, instead of plot.

Comment: @PeaceWang Yeah, somebody gave me advice that the mean_data and sd_data should be linked and though they are seperated now.Just like the answer blow

Comment: @PeaceWang thans,I get the right answer. And the problem is regarding plotdata() below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that errorbar reacts instantly if you keep sd in a separate dataframe.  Once you put sd into mean_data it works as desired.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))


###
ui <- fluidPage(

  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("123"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol",
        "123:",
        choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
        multiple =F,
        width = 400,
        selected = 1
      ),

      actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
      #uiOutput("all")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## put sd into mean_data
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })

  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
    req(plotdata())
    ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]], fill=Name,
                                  ymin = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]] - sd, ymax = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]] + sd )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "123_value")
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p1()
  })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Vary thankful. You helped me several times. Best.

I found the problem this time but I couldn't solve it by myself. thanks.

Comment: Could you explain about ".data" above? I get none useful information about it.Plz.

Comment: .data retrieves data-variables from the data frame. It means  ".data"  on belf of the data above "plotdata"  or "df"  ??

Comment: `.data` refers to `plotdata()`.  Also, `.data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]]` refers to the gene column selected by the user.

Comment: Yeah，I knew it before you tell me this. I'm so excited that you help me so much.  Thank you very much.

I use this method because I wanna reduce the running time of my code but now it's not perfect.

So I go back and still use only one  data matrix as my input .

And there is another data contains logfc, cil,cir and so on . I can't divided it into pieaces  and use this method. On the contrary, it my increase my workload if I use "mutate" to merge all of them.

Comment: Sorry,master, I hope you can view my this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654004/barplot-in-shiny-when-click-the-actionbutton-the-second-barplot-always-appear  in your spare time. Thanks again.