# Barplot in shiny: when click the actionbutton, the second barplot always appear delay and the previous figure appears

Tags: r, button, shiny

I create a barplot shiny app.

The biggest problem I met now is when I click the acitonbutton to get a new picture ,
the barplot appear delay and when I choose another input and click actionbutton again, the last barplot will appear but instantly disappear and the second picture appear.

**But the input first and second time is different. Why the first picture will appear twice?**

Here is my sample code,it is normal because it's a small sample.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))


###
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("123"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol",
        "123:",
        choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
        multiple =F,
        width = 400,
        selected = 1
      ),
      
      actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
      tags$h6(tags$a(href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "link",target = "_top"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
      #uiOutput("all")
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## put sd into mean_data
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })
  
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
    ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]], fill=Name,
                                  ymin = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] - sd, ymax = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] + sd )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p1()
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My real data is huge and I don't know if it is the main reason.

**Or I should  change the reactive() and EventReactive()  or adjust the parameters ??**

**My sample data here is simple. You may not meet what the problem I met in my code.**

I will show you some details, just like this:

[image]

That's ok.Though it may appeare slowly.

But when I choose another gene as input,

the first "Gene_1" result will appear again and then the "Gene_2"  result will appear.

[image]

I hope somebody could help me or met this problem before.

Vary thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is large, there is a delay in generating the plot `p1()`.  Hence, the previous plot is shown in `renderPlot`.  The following update will show blank until a new plot is generated whenever user selects a new gene.  Perhaps this will solve your issue.  I cannot verify as I don't have large dataframe.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("123"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol",
        "123:",
        choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
        multiple =F,
        width = 400,
        selected = 1
      ),
      
      actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
      tags$h6(tags$a(href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "link",target = "_top"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
      #,verbatimTextOutput("all")
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$selectGeneSymbol, {rv(0)})
  ## put sd into mean_data
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
    rv(0)
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })
  
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
    req(plotdata())
    p <- ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]], fill=Name,
                                  ymin = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] - sd, ymax = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] + sd )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
    rv(1)
    p
  })
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {rv(1)})
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (rv()) {
      p1() 
    } 
  })
  #output$all <- renderPrint(rv())
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```